# gpg symmetric encryption not working as expected

Tags: security, gnupg

How am I supposed to use gpg to symmetrically encrypt a file? When I run `gpg --symmetric filename`, then it prompts me for passwords as expected, and generates a `filename.gpg` file. However, when I run `gpg -d filename.gpg`, it returns

```
gpg: CAST5 encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
SECRET DATA HERE
gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected
```

**without asking for the password**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent versions of GnuPG come with a helper program *gpg-agent*, which handles the key and password operations and acts as a password cache. It could be that *gpg-agent* has cached the password you just entered.

To flush the cache, use either:

- `echo reloadagent | gpg-connect-agent`
- send SIGHUP: `pkill -HUP -U $USER gpg-agent`

Comment: When encrypting is there a way to tell gpg not to cache passwords?

Comment: @nullUser: It's always done by gpg-agent, so you can set very low cache-ttl's in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`.